# My image stays pixelated when rendered, any clues on what I can do? (Cycles render)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a problem to which I have not found the solution yet. I designed a logo, which I must deliver in different resolutions.
No matter how high I set the resolution and the sample amount (I even tried rediculously high 11000x11000 pixels and 4096 samples), when zooming in the image looks pixelated (in similar question I found on the net, upping the resolution and samples are usually given as the solution but this doesn't work for me). This is a problem for use in example instagram or facebook profile pic.

The strange thing is that when I'm in rendered mode (with 128 samples), I can zoom in maximally, and still have a sharp image!?

Some tips apart from upping resolution and sample size would be greatly apreciated.
Here is the blend file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v33alz6h95jhqn/LOGO_OPGEPOETST_11052020.blend?dl=0

And here is an example of the rendered image on 1100x1100 pixels and 2048 samples:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqj1qeb5lq3zzl4/LOGO1100x1100.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance!
Elvin

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How far do you zoom in? Any zoom level higher than 100% will give you pixels, due to the nature of PNG being a pixel format. In your posted image I can see no pixelation at 100% or lower. 
In viewport render mode, any zooming will re-render the image, so it will always look crisp no matter the zoom level!

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer! The image I added is the format for insta profile pic, 10x the size (I already tried the normal size of 110x110 and a few in between). It just doesn't look that good because of lack of sharpness. Same goes for facebook profile and overview image. I just wonder if there's a way to get a sharp image in those cases, both on pc and phone. I'll have a try in an editor, see if I can make it better.

Comment: I still don't get what your problem is... Maybe you could show a high-res image versus your screenshot from "rendered mode" and highlight the areas which are lacking sharpness? 
Still, the example image looks pretty crisp to me when viewed at 100% zoom.

Also, maybe upload the images here directly instead of linking to your dropbox?

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi. This took me a while. I'm adding an IMGUR link that should clarify the problem. I need a rendered output, being able to zoom in (>100%) and zoom out (<100%), that stays sharp just as in the rendered view. I've tried to tweak antialiasing and other render settings, sampling, resolution, all to no avail. I know it's possible because I've seen many output images, zoomed in dramatically and still remaining sharp. Thanks in advance for any help. Here are the images, I hope it's ok like this https://imgur.com/a/9DomksL